Chrome starts very slowly in a Windows Docker container
In the screenshot below I run Chrome with verbose logging enabled in a Windows container and print the time of the command, it is 17:41:41. Then I check the time of the earlist log entry, it is 17:41:50. I.e., it took Chrome 9 seconds to even produce the very first log line.

More observations:

Tried running Chrome in a Linux container, it starts instantly there.
Tried running Chrome locally on Windows or in a Windows container in my local Docker, it starts instantly. Same for Linux container in my local Docker.
Tried running Chromium in a Windows container, it has the same 9 seconds delay.
Tried Edge (which is Chromium-based) in a Windows or Linux container, it starts instantly as well.

Where do I even start? Clearly Chrome and Chromium have some issues with Windows containers. Unfortunately, their logs don't seem to be useful, as they are clearly doing something for around 9 seconds before they even start logging.

Logging will slow down Chrome, why not disable logging?

@Asesh, without logs it is as slow as with logs. I enabled logging for debugging purposes, to try to figure out what takes so much time at startup. And, apparently, this "something" happens even before the first log line appears.
